# Organizing Selenium tests in Django

Tags: django-testing

I am trying to organize my selenium tests better in a Django project.

I have a folder `project/app/selenium_tests/` into which I placed an `__init__.py`, and a `tests.py` which contains my selenium tests. in the `__init__.py` I import the tests like so:

```
from tests import *
```

But when I do `./manage.py test app.selenium_tests` I get:

```
ValueError: Test label 'app.selenium_tests' does not refer to a test
```

What could I be missing here? I even added a models.py to the selenium_test package but no joy.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I guess it's the discovery specifics of the Django-Selenium test runner, try to look at it's code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the folder `selenium_tests` under the `tests` directory of the app, otherwise the default Django test runner will not find it.

so, move this `project/app/selenium_tests/` to `project/app/tests/selenium_tests/`